# Web view client in .Net Maui

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maui

I'm not sure why my code is not working. But I am trying to use "OnReceivedClientCertRequest" callback so I can use my certificate. I have creatd a custom webview

```
public class CustomWebview:WebView
{
        
}
```

Using it on my xaml like so

```
 <local:CustomWebview x:Name="myWebview" Source="https://dweb.test.co.za"/>
```

I created my MyWebClient

```
 public class MyWebClient:WebViewClient
    {
        public override void OnReceivedClientCertRequest(Android.Webkit.WebView view, ClientCertRequest request)
        {
            base.OnReceivedClientCertRequest(view, request);
        }
        public override void OnReceivedError(Android.Webkit.WebView view, [GeneratedEnum] ClientError errorCode, string description, string failingUrl)
        {
            base.OnReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }
        public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
        {
            base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
        }
        public override void OnPageStarted(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url, Bitmap favicon)
        {
            base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
        public override void OnReceivedSslError(Android.Webkit.WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error)
        {
            base.OnReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
        }
    }
```

Then in my App class

```
 public void HandleWebview()
    {
#if ANDROID
         Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WebViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(CustomWebview), (handler, view) =>
        {
            handler.PlatformView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Yellow);
            handler.PlatformView.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());
        });
        
#endif
```

The webview does turn yellow but i am not sure why my methods in MyWebviewClient are not firing.

Comment: This api is used to notify the host application to handle a SSL client certificate request. Does the website have one?

Comment: Yes this works when using rebderes the api gets called

Comment: Did you try some other websites who will notity the host application to handle a SSL client certificate request?

Comment: Yes same issue. When I use custome renderer the method gets called but it doesn’t with handlers. I don’t want to use renderers as they are obsolete in Maui

Comment: Did the other methods get called? This appears to be a bug, you can ty to report it on the repo.